# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in modules\field\field.info.class.inc on line 512

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying to setup Drupal project on local machine and using XAMPP 1.8.X 
When I browse URL then its showing error  Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\XXXXXX\XXXXXXX\modules\field\field.info.class.inc on line 512

Here is code from line no. 512

```
 public function prepareInstance($instance, $field_type) {
// Make sure all expected instance settings are present.
$instance['settings'] += field_info_instance_settings($field_type);

// Set a default value for the instance.
if (field_behaviors_widget('default value', $instance) == FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT && !isset($instance['default_value'])) {
  $instance['default_value'] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: What type of variable is $instance['settings'] and what is field_info_instance_settings($field_type) returning? Can you var_dump() both of those and edit the output into the question? One of those values (or both) may not be able to be used in addition.

Comment: This is Drupal code module and didn't touched any code...
 $instance['settings'] is an array type and  field_info_instance_settings($field_type) returning this also return an array 
I am using PHP 5.4.3

Comment: What 'field' modules do you have installed? It seems to be a problem with one of them.